# print content of a div except some element in it, doesnt work

Tags: javascript, hide, print-preview

I want to print content of a div, and don't want to show some element in this div in print preview, I tried to give noprint class to those element in @media print, but no success! please help!
this is Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PrintPanel() {
        var panel = document.getElementById("content");
        var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
        printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
        printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        printWindow.document.write(panel.innerHTML);
        printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        printWindow.document.close();
        setTimeout(function () {
            printWindow.print();
        }, 500);
        return false;
    }

</script>
```

this is css

```
<style>
    .noprint {
        color: red;
    }

    @media print {
        p {
            color: green;
        }

        .noprint {
            display: none;
        }
    }
</style>
```

and this is html

```
<body>
<div id="content">
    <p>show this, in print preview</p>

    <div class="noprint">
        dont show this, in print preview!
    </div>
</div>
<a id="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print" onclick="PrintPanel();" style="cursor:pointer;">print</a>
```

I provide a sample in jsfiddle:
[sample link](https://jsfiddle.net/457vjehs/5/)

Comment: You have not loaded the CSS into your new window.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the newly created window using `window.open` does not have any style attached to it.

Here is a snapshot

[image: Snapshot of the newly created window]

Style can be added to it by adding inline style in the following code

```
printWindow.document.write('<html><head><style media="print">' +
            'p {color: green;}.noprint {display: none !important;}</style><title>DIV Contents</title>');
```

Comment: yes, thanks this worked, only with some modification, I removed media="print" from your code and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

i added this code to delete the element before render in the pop up really simple!
This code only get the element by a query like $() of Jquery and is removed from the parent node **panel** with the method removeChild(element) in this case your div.

```
var el = document.querySelector('.noprint');
panel.removeChild(el);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/457vjehs/6/

Comment: This does not really answer the question of why it's not working.

Comment: thanks, it worked and is great help, but I need to know why this part doesn't work  @media print {
            p
            {
                color:green;
            }
            .noprint {
                display: none;
                
            }

Comment: the @media print doesn't works cuz the css rule never gonna enter into a print document thats why you add a new html with document.write check this fiddle in JS https://jsfiddle.net/457vjehs/10/ line 5